# WordPress wp_enque_style different behaviour than <link href=...>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am having a trouble trying to use a JavaScript code for upload files (http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) in WordPress.

Following the recommendations of WordPress, I have created a plugin that enqueues the scripts and the styles required by the JavaScript code. The appearance of the script is:

```
function add_mini_ajax_file_upload_scrips() {
wp_enqueue_style('uploadBoxStyleFont', "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" );
wp_enqueue_style('uploadBoxStyle', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/css/style.css" );
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxJquerymin', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxJqueryknob', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.knob.js");
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxJquerywidget', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.ui.widget.js");
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxJqueryiframe', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js");
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxJqueryupload', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.fileupload.js");
wp_enqueue_script('uploadBoxScript', "http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/script.js");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_mini_ajax_file_upload_scrips' );
```

In this manner, the WordPress page looks as:
[image]

As yo can see, a button with the text "Examinar ..." appears very uggly below the "Browse" button.

However, if I paste the following code directly on the WordPress Page:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />
<link href="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/assets/MiniAJAX_FileUploader/js/script.js"></script>
```

Then the page looks:
[image]

Obviously, I want the appearance of the second way but WordPress recommends the first way to add JavaScript and styles.

Someone can tell me what is happening and how can I get the correct appearance (removing the uggly "Examinar" button)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ok please can you share a url

Comment: The files in the first `wp_enqueue_script` batch and the files in the second batch `<script> </script>` have different paths.

Comment: Yes, but it is a mistake. Both ways load the same scripts. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the order in which scripts/styles are loaded. Most likely, they are loaded in different order.

WordPress assigns a unique id to each enqueued style-sheet or script as either `unique-id-css` or `unique-id-js`. You can see it in the generated `<link>` or `<script>` tag if you look in page source.

You can use those ids (without the `-css` or `-js` part) to modify the order in which styles or scripts are loaded by passing the id in the array of dependencies ($deps)  of `wp_enqueue_script` or `wp_enqueue_style`.

You should stick to the WP way as it will avoid loading a resource multiple times which could cause hard to trace errors, especially for js scripts.

For example, If you load them directly and another plugin/widget/theme script loads jquery, it will be loaded twice in your page, causing conflicts.

Also please note jquery is already provided by WP,  you don't  need to load it from external source. Just specify it as dependence for any jquery dependant script.

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Do you think that the problem is in the order in which these specific scripts and styles are loaded? Or for example, other Wordpress CSS styles (from the theme or anything else) can also influence?

Comment: You should not load jquery at all (first script). Instead, specify `array('jquery')` as third parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` for the rest of the scripts you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to the comment of Andrei

Following the Wordpress way, I wrote the scripts that uses `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` and hooks it to the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`. The solution is to introduce a priority value into the `add_action` to force the plugin to be added later. In my case, with priorty 11 has been enough (default is 10).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_mini_ajax_file_upload_scrips', 11 );
```

Bye and merry christmas!!

Comment: Please note that, even if it works like this, it will stop working when you use any other jquery dependant script in the same page, as jquery will be loaded twice. You need to specify `jquery` as dependency for scripts that rely on it, using `$deps` argument. And you shouldn't load `uploadBoxJquerymin` at all. That's `jquery` and is already provided by WP. If you depend on a specific jquery version you need to prevent WP loading default one and specify yours. But that's a different case and you shouldn't need it here.

Comment: Thanks for the info Andrei. In this case I think I need the 1.9.1 version specifically. I have tried to remove the `uploadBoxJquerymin` and make the other scripts dependent from jquery through the `$deps` array, but the code doesnt work. I think there should be something dependent from this version.